# Is the l'Hospital's Rule applicable in this case?

Tags: limits

Can I apply the L'Hospital rule in the exponent of a function of the form

$e^\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ 
 where for $x$ tending to $0$, $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ becomes $0/0$, and write it as **$e^\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Because the exponential function is continuois, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=c$ implies $\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}=e^c$. Whether or not you use l'Hopital to arrive at the intermediate result  $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=c$ is of no concern.